# Conditional declaration of objects inherting from a common base class to pass a reference to one of them

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, pass-by-reference

Say I have two classes inheriting from a common base, such as

```
class Thing{
public:
    virtual void f()=0;
};

class Thing_variant_a: public Thing{
public:
    void f(){
        std::cout<<"I am (a)"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class Thing_variant_b: public Thing{
public:
    void f(){
        std::cout<<"I am (b)"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

And a function taking a reference to a `Thing` object as an argument.

```
void function(Thing& t){
    t.f();
}
```

Depending on conditions I would like to call `function` with either a `thing_a` or `thing_b` (and possibly extend this at some point adding another possibility of `thing_c`)

I know I can do this using a pointer

```
Thing *t = nullptr;
if(condition_a){
    t = new Thing_variant_a();
} else if(condition_b){
    t = new Thing_variant_b();
}

function(*t);
```

However, I would like to know if there is a better way, that

- does not allocate heap memory
- does not require me to take care of deleting `t` at some point (probably smart pointers, but I don't know much about those)
- ensures I always pass a valid `Thing` reference to function (there might be more conditionals in a complicated structure than in this minimal example) I could do `if(t){ function(*t);}else{/*handle error*/}`), but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution.

If not all of the above are possible any combination of those?

Comment: Maybe try out `std::variant`?

Comment: Is a condition run-time or compile-time?

Comment: @Evg It is  a run-time condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very much like an XY problem. There is probably a different solution to your problem entirely.

C++ is a statically-typed language; that means types used in a given code path are fixed at compile-time. Dynamic types (types known at run time) are normally allocated via the heap or all-at-once and then selected at run time.

So not much is possible in your case as you've noticed..

You could for example just have two different code paths:

```
if (condition_a) {
    Thing_variant_a a;
    function(a);
} else if (condition_b) {
    Thing_variant_a b;
    function(b);
}
```

Preallocate the types:

```
Thing_variant_a a;
Thing_variant_a b;

if (condition_a) {
    function(a);
} else if (condition_b) {
    function(b);
}
```

Or use a template:

```
template<typename T>
void do_something() {
    T t;
    function(t);
}

// somewhere else in the code ...
do_something<Thing_variant_a>();

// or ...
do_something<Thing_variant_b>();
```

Here's a way using dynamic memory and `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> t;
if (condition_a) {
    t = std::make_unique<Thing_variant_a>();
} else if (condition_b) {
    t = std::make_unique<Thing_variant_b>();
}

function(*t);

// t is delete'd automatically at end of scope...
```

---

And by the way, a function like `int f(){...}` should return some `int` value.

Comment: You gave the most concise answer, so I am going to mark this as accepted, but I also like Jeremy's solution he gave in a comment of a factory function, which is somewhat similar to your Template suggestion. I changed the return type of f to void in my example. Thank you for taking the time to expand my knowledge about C++

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it without using the heap or pointers:

```
Thing_variant_a thingA;
Thing_variant_b thingB;

if(condition_a){
    function(thingA);
} else if(condition_b){
    function(thingB);
}
```

If you want, you reduce it to a single call via the ternary operator:

```
Thing_variant_a thingA;
Thing_variant_b thingB;
function(condition_a ? static_cast<Thing &>(thingA) : static_cast<Thing &>(thingB));
```

As far as references go, references in C++ are required to be always be non-NULL -- so if you try to dereference a NULL pointer (e.g. by calling `function(*t)` when `t==NULL`) you've already invoked undefined behavior and are doomed; there is nothing the code inside `function()` can do to save you.  So if there is any change that your pointer is NULL, you must check for that *before* dereferencing it.

Comment: This is a possibility, but variant a means a lot of code duplication depending on the signature of ```function``` and the complexity of the conditional structure. I have abbreviated all of that for the sake of a minimal example.

Comment: Variant b seems unsustainable for more than two options and for your comment on dereferencing NULL pointers, this is exactly why I am aware of that, hence I want to ensure the validity of the argument before calling ```function```

Comment: In that case maybe you want to just create a factory function `std::shared_ptr<Thing> CreateThing(int thingType)`, then you can call `function(*CreateThing(THING_TYPE_B))` or similar.  (To avoid the need for checking for NULL, you could code `CreateThing()` to never return a NULL shared_ptr; e.g. it could return a Thing_variant_error if it gets called with an unrecognized argument)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer each of your questions

> does not allocate heap memory

Unfortunately c++ only supports polymorphism using pointers. I guess the problem you would face here is fragmented memory (meaning that your pointers are everywhere in the heap). The best way to handle that is to allocate the memory using a memory pool.

You could use an `std::variant` but you will still need to test for the currently available type in the variant.

> does not require me to take care of deleting t at some point (probably smart pointers, but I don't know much about those)

You could use a `std::unique_ptr` which will basically called the destructor when no one holds that pointer anymore.

> ensures I always pass a valid Thing reference to function (there might be more conditionals in a complicated structure than in this minimal example) I could do if(t){ function(*t);}else{/*handle error*/}), but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution.

If you use pointers your could just check for the `nullptr` as you are doing right now. I'm not sure what you are meaning by valid reference as a reference always points toward something and cannot be empty.